# How can I take values from textbox and assign it to integer variable in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

how can I convert the valuesof textbox to numeric?
here's what I'm doing:

```
int el = electric.text;
int wb = waterbill.text;
int inet = internet.text;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int el = [electric integerValue];
int wb = [waterbill integerValue];
int inet = [internet integerValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NsInteger el = [electric.text integerValue];
NsInteger wb = [waterbill.text integerValue];
NsInteger inet = [internet.text integerValue];
```